# problem with preg_replace

Tags: php

I use this function to make links clickable:

```
function clickable($text) {
   $text = preg_replace("/(https?|ftps?|mailto):\/\/([-\w\p{L}\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w\p{L}#-;+-\/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?/u", '<a target="_blank" href="$0">$0</a>', $text);
   return $text;
}
```

It works fine but there is one little problem. If the $text variable contains a string like this:

> http://example.com
>
> some text

i.e. link, line break(s) and some text, I get incorrect result. Instead of this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a>
```

it becomes:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://example.com<br">http://example.com</a>
/>

some text
```

Here is how I display text on my site:

```
<?php echo clickable(nl2br($db['content'])); ?>
```

nl2br function converts all line breaks into html `<br />` tags but this function thinks it should keep this tag in url...

Hope I'm clear :)

Any ideas?

Comment: You have a character class with `[#-;+-\\]` - is this intentional? For one, `[#-;]` contains `[+-\\]`, which is weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of your pattern you have `\S+` - this allows all non-space characters, including `<`, and the reason your regex doesn't work as expected. I'm not quite sure what is the role of that part, consider removing the `(\?\S+)?` and see if it's working for you.

Another option is changing that group to: `[^\s<]*` - this will not capture spaces and the `<` sign, solving exactly this problem...

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to be a good solution... If I remove this part and there are some special symbols in utl, for example ? or - only the part before that symbols is shown as url.

Comment: @Levani - I just explained what is causing your error - I've updated my answer with a possible solution. Note that `\S` is quite a strong selector... Anyway, I simplified `(\?\S+)?` into `[^\s<]*` - it contains \ anyway, and `*` seems more appropriate here.